# Use .eslintrc from /home with eslint installed globally in VScode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

It is possible to use a .eslintrc for all projets that I open in VScode with eslint installed globally ?

I would like to use my .eslintrc in my home,
when I open a project an eslint error appear in VScode console.

`Failed to load plugin prettier: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'
Happened while validating /home/**/**/**/constants.js
This can happen for a couple of reasons:
1. The plugin name is spelled incorrectly in an ESLint configuration file (e.g. .eslintrc).
2. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure 'eslint-plugin-prettier' is installed globally as well.
3. If ESLint is installed locally, then 'eslint-plugin-prettier' isn't installed correctly.`

But before I run this command:

```
npm install -g eslint@^3.19.0 eslint-config-airbnb@^15.0.1 eslint-config-prettier@^2.9.0 eslint-loader@^1.8.0 eslint-plugin-import@^2.7.0 eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^5.0.1 eslint-plugin-prettier@^2.6.1 eslint-plugin-react@^7.1.0
```

here my .eslintrc in `/user/home/.eslintrc`

```
{
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"plugins": ["react", "jsx-a11y", "import", "prettier"],
"extends": ["react-app", "airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
"env": {
    "browser": true
},
"rules": {
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0,
    "import/extensions": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "no-console": 0,
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 2,
    "no-confusing-arrow": 0,
    "import/no-webpack-loader-syntax": 0,
    "no-return-assign": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": 0,
    "react/no-array-index-key": 0,
    "no-mixed-operators": 0,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 0,
    "react/require-default-props": 0,
    "prettier/prettier": [
        "error",
        {
            "trailingComma": "es5",
            "singleQuote": true,
            "printWidth": 120
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried installing it directly from VS Code? Just click Crl+Shift+X from VS Code to open extensions, then enter 'ESLint' on the search bar and install.

Comment: I edit the question, this is the .eslintrc that I want read with VScode, thanks.